# Do something else only whilst shell_exec is running?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I have a shell_exec command to run some video conversion with FFMPEG. As it runs, it prints the log to a text file.

Whilst this is running, I'd like to read that log file, say once a second.

How can I start my shell_exec and do another process (reading the file) only whilst the command is running?

Something like:

```
while shell_exec:
    read file and output contents;
endwhile;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do anything else while the process you spawned with `shell_exec` is running. You will need to use `proc_open` instead, in which case you can also redirect ffmpeg's standard output so perhaps the log file will not be needed as an intermediary.

Comment: I'll look into proc_open. In the mean time, how could I fire off the shell_exec command, and at the same time, hit a script via ajax to get the log file info?